# How to add custom data to claim during login process?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I was reading article from [here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.in/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html)

This way we can add claim during login

```
var user = userManager.Find(userName, password);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = persistCookie }, identity);
```

This way reading back the value stored in clam

```
var prinicpal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
var email = prinicpal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

### Now I have few questions

1. How could I add my custom data to claim. Suppose user role names.
   Suppose the things I want to add that is not available in `ClaimTypes` then how could I add my custom data to claim?
2. How to read back my custom data stored in claim?
3. My action is decorated with authorized attribute where role name is specified like below one:

..

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
     [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, HrAdmin")]
     public ActionResult PayRoll()
     {
         return View();
     }
  }
```

Do I need to go for custom authentication to extract roles from claim to set in `GenericPrincipal`?

Last question: When we go for role based authorization then roles are stored in authorization cookie? Do I need to write code to store roles in authorization cookie or ASP.net engine does it for us?

Same way claims are store in authorization cookie generated by owin cookie?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Identity than identity have its own method which can handle roles and everything you just have to login with this line.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

you will have to add role manager in Identity Config File

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
        { }

        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(
            IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options,
            IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(
                new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            return manager;
        }
    }
```

and register in Startup.Auth.cs

```
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

and you won't have to give roles to the authentication manually. you just have to write

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, HrAdmin")]
```

if you want to add that manually without identity given method than use this below

```
private void IdentityLogin(UserInfo UserInfo)
        {
            // Waleed: added the role in the claim
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserInfo.Email),
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, UserInfo.UserID),
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, UserInfo.Roles)
                                }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            // Set current principal
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

            var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authManager = ctx.Authentication;
            authManager.SignIn(identity);
        }
```

Claims are of two types one are in your session and other are stored in db. Session Claims are above in IdentityLogin method and db claims can be written as

```
    UserManager.AddClaim(userId,new Claim())
```

Comment: thanks for your code. your first code where roles are set automatically not clear. if roles set automatically then how system understand what values we are going to store in role ? does it fetch role data automatically from db based on user id ?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar when you login using this

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

it adds the claims for roles. It fetches the data from db all user info like email, id, roles and stores them in claims, session claims to be precise

Comment: please post another set of code where u will show how to work with db claims.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar you are having trouble with Role claims or db claims. Db claims are the one which can have any type of data