# Add claims to a user during login using Identity in ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

### Edit 2:

Finally figured out. Check out the accepted answer below.

### Edit:

Full source code with my attempt as instructed by @Jason Pan.
https://github.com/affableashish/blazor-server-auth/tree/feature/AddClaimsDuringLogin

Added Claims during Login (in [Login.cshtml.cs](https://github.com/affableashish/blazor-server-auth/blob/bab11ae89e3e3f1120b523f8688ca91c3ff71dff/src/HMT.Web.Server/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml.cs#L121) file) and accessed those claims from [Razor Component](https://github.com/affableashish/blazor-server-auth/blob/bab11ae89e3e3f1120b523f8688ca91c3ff71dff/src/HMT.Web.Server/Areas/Identity/Components/TakeABreak.razor#L17).

Unfortunately, it didn't work. I only get `null` as the claim value.

---

### Original Question

I've seen some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66935383/8644294) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39616938/8644294), but they weren't helpful for my scenario.

My application is a **Blazor Server** project where I have added **Identity** following the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-blazor-server-project).

Now this is what I want to achieve:

1. User enters their credentials.
2. If the username is valid (in our Active Directory), I retrieve a field known as `EmployeeId` from the Active Directory.
3. Authenticate the user using `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`.
4. Add `EmployeeId` as a claim to the ClaimsPrincipal. (So that I can use `EmployeeId` from Razor Components [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter)).

I'm struggling to figure out how to add this `EmployeeId` as claims **during the login process**.

My `OnPostAsync` method in `Login.cshtml.cs` looks like this:

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<MMTUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<MMTUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Step 1: Check if this user exists in our AD
            // If YES: Grab the Employee Id and go to next step
            // If NO: Terminate the process
            var adLookupResult = ADHelper.ADLookup(Input.Username);
            if (adLookupResult == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(adLookupResult.EmployeeId))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }

            // Step 2: SignIn the user
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, isPersistent: Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            // Step 3: How do I add adLookupResult.EmployeeId to the ClaimsPrincipal?

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
    
    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this out by asking a question in **aspnetcore** github repo.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46558

Much thanks to @Piotr Stola and @Jason Pan for their help!

### Step 1:

In `OnPostAsync` method in `Login.cshtml.cs`, use `_signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync` instead of `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Step 1: Check if this user exists in our AD
        // If YES: Grab the Employee Id and go to next step
        // If NO: Terminate the process
        var adLookupResult = // Call Active Directory and get EmployeeId of this user here
        if (adLookupResult == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(adLookupResult.EmployeeId))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "User doesn't exist.");
            return Page();
        }

        // Step 2: Check if the user exists in our Identity database (AspNetUsers table)
        var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "User doesn't exist.");
            return Page();
        }
        
        // Step 3: Check the credentials of this user.
        var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // Access 'EmployeeId' from Areas/Identity/Components/TakeABreak.razor
            // For eg: Emp123 is adLookupResult.EmployeeId that I retrieved from Active Directory in Step 1.
            var customClaims = new[] { new Claim("EmployeeId", "Emp123") };
            await _signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, Input.RememberMe, customClaims);
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

### Step 2:

Access this from any Razor component. For eg: I'm accessing it from `TakeABreak.razor` component (Line Number 15 in the attached picture).

[image]

### Full Source Code

https://github.com/akhanalcs/blazor-server-auth/tree/feature/AddClaimsDuringLogin

Comment: Thanks - was very much clueless until I found your solution! Seems like a downgrade from the relative simplicity of the ASP.NET MVC identity....

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

The previous solution could be a workaround if put in middleware. That very terrible.

We should use CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory to fix the issue.

[image]

**CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs**

```
using HMT.Web.Server.Areas.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace HMT.Web.Server
{
    public class CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory :
        UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<HMTUser>
    {
        public CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory(
            UserManager<HMTUser> userManager,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
                : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
        {
        }

        // This method is called only when login. It means that "the drawback   
        // of calling the database with each HTTP request" never happen.  
        public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(HMTUser user)
        {
            var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

            if (principal.Identity != null)
            {
                //((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(
                //    new[] { new Claim("EmpId", user.EmpId) });
                ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(
                    new[] { new Claim("EmpId", "EmpId123") });
            }

            return principal;
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs or Startup.cs**

```
// Learned the hard way that this needs to be added after setting up Blazor (i.e. AddRazorPages, AddServerSideBlazor) - AshishK
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<HMTUser>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<HMTUser>, CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

For more details, you can check [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1009750/how-to-add-custom-claims-on-user-identity-net-6).

---

When you login uscessfully, you can use `HttpContext.User.AddIdentity` to achieve that. Sample like below:

```
   // Step 3: Add the EmployeeId to ClaimsPrincipal
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, adLookupResult.EmployeeId)
        }));
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Comment: I did this but I get a null value when I retrieve the claim. In `Login.cshtml.cs`, I wrote this after `result.Succeeded`: `HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("NewClaim", "Emp123") }));`
And in a Razor Component, I try to retrieve it using `[CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }`, and call this in the code: 
`var empId = (await authenticationStateTask).User.FindFirstValue("NewClaim");`
I get `empId` as `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Edited my question to link the full source code showing my attempt as per your instruction. Please take a look if you get some time. Thank you!

Comment: @AshK Sorry, at the first I haven't test, now I have test and it works, pls check the latest answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update, but I have one problem with it. How do I pass `adLookupResult.EmployeeId` to the `public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(HMTUser user)` method? `adLookupResult.EmployeeId` is not stored in any Identity table and it comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Also looks like this method is called during Logout as well. That's not required though.

Comment: Figured this out. I posted my answer below. Thank you for your help.