# How to implement either AspNetUserClaims or AspNetRoleClaim base authorization in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, jwt, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-authorization

In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I am trying to claim based authorization using ASP.NET Core Identity and JWT.

I have declared a set of claims within the `AddAuthorization` middleware like

```
options.AddPolicy(AppPermissions.Root_Users_Create, 
                  policy => policy.RequireRole(AppPermissions.Root_Users_Create))
```

where `AppPermissions` is a static class containing a set of permission names.

In my case I want to validate a user to access an API in 2 ways.

1. If the `AppPermissions.Root_Users_Create` claims is assigned directly to the user by storing to `AspNetUserClaims` table.
2. Or the claim `AppPermissions.Root_Users_Create` is assigned to a role say `User` by storing in table `AspNetRoleClaims`, and then the role `User` is assigned to `User`.

If any of the 2 options are applied to a User, then s/he will be eligible to access the api. Fortunately, the first one is working, but unfortunately 2nd one is not working. For the 2nd one, identity does not automatically grant the permissions assigned to the role, as the permissions for the user.

I am declaring my API like this:

```
[HttpPost("CreateOrEditUser")]
[Authorize(Policy = AppPermissions.Root_Users_Create)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrEditUser(CreateOrEditUserInput input)
```

What is the most efficient and practiced way to implements this mechanism?

Comment: Please try to [add custom claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75377386/add-claims-to-a-user-during-login-using-identity-in-asp-net-core-web-app/75380644#75380644) in your AspNetUserClaims .

Comment: @JasonPan The link you provided, did not cleared my issue. Can you explain, how it works and resolve my issue?

Comment: Seems I misunderstand the question, could your create a brand new sample for us to investigate the issue further.

Comment: I resolved the issue. The problem was access token was not adding the claims assigned via role